# EXECUTE permission denied on SQL stored procedure even though I can run it in MS SQL Server with the same account

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc

I have a stored procedure I'm trying to run from a web backend.  The SQL admin checked and rechecked that the account I'm using has EXECUTE permissions on this particular procedure, and I have no problem running it inside MS SQL studio.  But when I try running the same thing with pyodbc/sqlalchemy I get an error.  Every other query works fine for me.

Here is the error:

> (pymssql.OperationalError) (229, b"The EXECUTE permission was denied
>   on the object '.....', databse '......', schema '.....'.DB-Lib error
>   message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages
>   from the SQL Server\n") [SQL: "....."] (Background on this error at
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to run it with SQL management studio? just to check that you have the rights from there?

Comment: there might be more than 1 stored procedure with the same name in different schemas. Also check this. Else make sure you refer to the stored procedure with the full name including database.schema.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using a wrapper function and passing the engine, but it was the wrong parameter order and I forgot to pass the parameter name, so I was passing the engine not as the engine but as a parameter of the query.  The error message, while it makes sense now, was not very helpful and had me chasing the wrong problem.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: i am glad you sorted it and updated us.

Comment: So in the future, the first thing you should assume is that your code is the source of the problem and start looking there. Learn to debug - it is a skill you must master to be successful.

Comment: Of course that is the first assumption.  I've been writing python code for over a decade now.  I looked at this bug since yesterday and I just couldn't see it for whatever reason.  My colleague eventually pointed it out, so I really shouldn't have said "I figured it out."